# how to show count on the basis of column and latest status SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table order like this

```
   ID | name    | status |   Year
_______________________________________ 
    1  |f1 car  | enter    |2017
    2  |f2 car  | checking |2019
    3  |f3 car  | enter    |2017
    4  |f2 car  | enter    |2018
    5  |f3 car  | checking |2019
    6  |f2 car  | exit     |2020
    7  |f3 car  | exit     |2020
    8  |f1 car  | checking |2018
    9  |f4 car  | enter    |2019
   10  |f5 car  |enter     |2019
   11  |f4 car  |checking  |2020
```

there are 3 things `name , status and year` i want it to get the most recent  status wise count based on year and counts of cars

`'enter'` is the first status of every car means if a car is there in table first status will be `enter`

then checking then
like this what i want to get after query

```
enter | checking | exit
_______________________
 1    |2         | 2
```

this is the most recent year wise car count status

how can i achieve this in SQL

the workaround i have for it is first i get the car list which have `status 'enter'`
now i have 5 car name which i put in a `temp table`

now i will iterate over `temp table` and search in the order table by name pick the last status based on year and put it in a table

then again on the second row of temp table i will select a car name and iterate over order table and get the last status of second row car

please let me know what else can be done

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, and SQL Server 2008 is *completely* unsupported. What are you actually using (and why haven't you upgraded)?

Comment: I am using using sql server 2019

Comment: Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function.

Comment: *like this what i want to get after query* Do not post "like" - the sample output must match shown sample data FULLY. If some additional paraneter values are used they must be specified.

Comment: *'enter' is the first status of every car means if a car is there in table first status will be enter* Does this is provided by according constraint? show source table's DDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and aggregation.  If you are content with the results in separate *rows* rather than *columns*, this is simply:

```
select status, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by year desc) as seqnum
      from orders t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by status;
```

Comment: i have replaced it but still The column prefix 't' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: i can not replace t with my table at all places in this query as t.* is also used in it

Comment: @fatboy . . . I updated the answer.  But you should learn what table aliases are.

Answer (score 0):

The query may look like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       name,
       FIRST_VALUE(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY Year ASC, ID ASC) first_row,
       COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY name) total_rows_count,
       MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'enter' THEN Year END) OVER (PARTITION BY name) entering_year,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'checking' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY name) checkings_count,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'exit' THEN Year END) OVER (PARTITION BY name) exit_year
FROM cars;
```

You may add any additional columns by creating according argument expressions and window definitions.

---

Or maybe you need in simple

```
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT DISTINCT name,
                         FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY Year DESC, ID DESC) status
         FROM cars )
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'enter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) enter,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'checking' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) checking,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'exit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [exit]
FROM cte
```

?

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e84164bff9d571ee820d92327ca708c9)

Comment: its something else @akina its not what i am looking for

Comment: @fatboy *its not what i am looking for* If you want to obtain "what you're looking for" then you must give additional explanations. As I have already said in a comment to the question, the sample output must match shown sample data FULLY. And the best way is to explain how each separate value in output is obtained from shown sample source data.

Comment: ok let me explain you , a car enter in a garage , it has 3 status for its life ,

Comment: when its enter the status is enter , when it got checked status is checking , when its goes out status is exit ,

Comment: so every car first status is enter then its change to checking and exit as the time passes

Comment: @fatboy I.e. you need to count the amounts by final state? if so then look for 2nd query in the answer. PS. fiddle added.

Comment: so in my desired out put (center ,checking , exit ) ->(1-2-2 ) as currently only one car is there whose last status is enter all other cars was having enter status earlier but their recent status is not enter

Comment: so if we want to get unique car list we can just select from order table where status is "enter"

Comment: @fatboy Again - prove it !!! As I have commented, "Does this is provided by according constraint? show source table's DDL." If such constraint not exists then your phrase may become false easily in any moment - data damage, including errorneous altering/deletion, is always possible.